# How to pass a dynamic parameter to like operator in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I need to search based on any word in between the data. How can I pass the parameter in stored procedure for that ?

```
where like employeename concat(empname,'%')
```

doesn't work,

It getting only gets starting emp names...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need wildcard markers at both ends of the search term. Using the `||` operator is less typing :)

```
 select * 
 from emp
 where ename like '%' || p_name || '%'
```

To do the same with `concat()` requires two calls to the function:

```
 select * 
 from emp
 where ename like concat('%', concat(p_name, '%'))
```

Comment: Using `concat()` wouldn't be possible anyway because Oracle's `concat()` doesn't support more then two arguments

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - not using `concat()` *once*, no

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean with "less typing" ;)